# Symfony2 cannot connect to sqlite

Tags: php, mysql, sqlite, symfony, behat

Im trying to use sqlite base in my behat tests in symfony2. As far as im am, behat in symfony2 finds my base, and can create fixtures in it. Problem is my test site cannot connect to this base.

This is my `config_test.yml`:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_sqlite
        host:     127.0.0.1
        dbname:   "%database_name%_test"
        path:     tests/eg_test.db
```

This is my `config.yml`:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
```

This is my `behat.yml`:

```
default:
    suites:
        default:
            paths:
                features: '%paths.base%/features'
                bootstrap:  '%paths.base%/features/bootstrap'
            contexts:
                - FeatureContext: ~
                - EwidencjaContext:
                    userManager: '@fos_user.user_manager'
                    em: '@doctrine.orm.entity_manager'
                    packageManager: '@em.package_manager'
    extensions:
        Behat\Symfony2Extension: ~
        Behat\MinkExtension:
            base_url:  http://nginx/app_test.php
            goutte: ~
            selenium2:
                browser: "chrome"
                wd_host: http://selenium_chrome:4444/wd/hub
                capabilities: { "browserName": "chrome", "browser": "chrome"}
        Bex\Behat\ScreenshotExtension:
            image_drivers:
                local:
                    screenshot_directory: tests/features/images/
                    clear_screenshot_directory: true
```

This is log i get back after trying to log into my site. Doesn't matter if user exists or not. So its not fault of wrong password or something like that. Seems like site just dont connect to base.

> [2017-03-27 10:22:09] request.INFO: Matched route "fos_user_security_check". {"route":"fos_user_security_check","route_parameters":{"_controller":"FOS\UserBundle\Controller\SecurityController::checkAction","_route":"fos_user_security_check"},"request_uri":"http://localhost/app_test.php/login_check","method":"POST"} []
>   [2017-03-27 10:22:10] security.INFO: Authentication request failed. {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationServiceException(code: 0): An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [14] unable to open database file at /var/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Provider/DaoAuthenticationProvider.php:94, Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException(code: 0): An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [14] unable to open database file at /var/www/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractSQLiteDriver.php:82, Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException(code: 14): SQLSTATE[HY000] [14] unable to open database file at /var/www/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:47, PDOException(code: 14): SQLSTATE[HY000] [14] unable to open database file at /var/www/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:43)"} []
>   [2017-03-27 10:22:10] security.DEBUG: Authentication failure, redirect triggered. {"failure_path":"/login"} []
>   [2017-03-27 10:22:10] request.INFO: Matched route "fos_user_security_login". {"route":"fos_user_security_login","route_parameters":{"_controller":"FOS\UserBundle\Controller\SecurityController::loginAction","_route":"fos_user_security_login"},"request_uri":"http://localhost/app_test.php/login","method":"GET"} []
>   [2017-03-27 10:22:10] security.INFO: Populated the TokenStorage with an anonymous Token. [] []

And this is error i get on my site when i try to log in from browser:

> Authentication request could not be processed due to a system problem.

And error when I try to register new user:

> An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [14] unable to open database file

I created my sqlite database as close to standard mysql base im using on prod. After it I used `bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force --env=test`. My database got good file mod (-rwxrwxr-x) and is used by right user and group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your config_test.yml to this:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        connections:
            default:
                driver: pdo_sqlite
                path: %kernel.cache_dir%/default.db
                charset: UTF8
```

And then grant correct permissions show in here: [Setting up or Fixing File Permissions](http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/file_permissions.html) You're going to run commands in either 2nd or 3rd depending on your operating system.

Comment: This works great! Thanks. I just dont understand one thing. This default.db is generated automaticly. Since its in cache dir ill lose it if ill do cache clear. How can i tell it to generate base with my tables and fixtures?

Comment: Ok, i found code to reset database from image in behat. `/**
     *@ BeforeScenario
     *
     * @Given the database is clean
     */
    public function theDatabaseIsClean()
    {
        exec('php app/console cache:clear --env=test');
        exec('php app/console doctrine:database:create --env=test --force');
        exec('php app/console doctrine:schema:update --env=test --force');
        exec('cp tests/features/database/eg_test.db var/cache/test/default.db');
    }`

Comment: You can do it with Symfony+Behat way like shown here: [Loading doctrine data fixtures before each behat scenarios within feature context file of symfony](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/ypah/loading-doctrine-data-fixtures-before-each-behat-scenarios-within-feature-context-file-of-symfony)

Answer (score 0):

If you go to your parameters.yml file you should see the path, something like this : `database_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/var/data/data.sqlite'`, another advise : create a directory in `/var` and put your `data.sqlite` file in it

Hope it helps :)